# How to add sql constrain of date only from field datetime odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How to add sql constrain of date only from field datetime

date = fields.Datetime('Date', store=True, default=fields.Datetime.now,
)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need sql restrictions. A better option is to extend the field and change its data type to Date:

```
class NewClass(models.Model):
    _inherit = "original.class"
    ...
    date = fields.Date('Date', store=True, default=fields.Date.today())
```

If you don't want to do this, use instead the constraints decorator over your field:

```
@api.constrains('date')
def check_data_type(self):
    if not condition:
        raise ValidationError("Error!")
```

In any case, if you still want to add a sql constraints you can use this in your model:

```
class YourClass(models.Model):
    _name = "your.class"
    ...
    _sql_constraints = [('date', 'CHECK (your check)', 'Data no pass the check')]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: But i want this field datetime not date

Comment: In that case use just the constraints decorator to handle this from python. If this isn't useful, why you need necessarily a sql constraints ?